# copied Xcode 5 Button does not correctly center align in IB in xcode 7 for all sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have read through several tutorials and stack overflow posts about this but I can't get it to work.

Here is what I'm doing:

- Create fresh Xcode project
- Add Button to center of default view in IB
- Make sure size is set to Any, Any
- click align button in lower right corner to Add New Alignment Constraint
- Check box for Horizontally in Center: 0

This works as expected. However, if I copy and paste a button from an existing project, and go through the same steps, I encounter problems.

For example, if I resize to a compact width, the new, copied button is not centered, and instead has a +100.5 next to its constraint.

I have compared the settings of the two buttons and they are the same.

What is the issue here?

I have a number of views from an old project (xcode 5) that I would not like to create, but all elements have this issue.

Comment: Have you asked Xcode to add the suggested auto layout constraints for you on the second screen?

Comment: Thank you. That was my missing step!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for future reference to this issue, the issue was related to not adding constraints on the second screen. One easy way to do that is by asking Xcode to add suggested constraints for you.

When you drag your button in the middle of screen, you can see that Xcode gives you some hints and shows you horizontal and/or vertical lines when you move the view in the middle of the screen. You can make sure that the view is in the middle of the screen if you can see both horizontal and vertical lines:

[image]

And then you can ask Xcode to add missing constraints for you by tapping the first item in the lower right, and choose `Add Missing Constraints`

[image]

For more information on Auto Layout and how to use it, I would suggest checking out Auto Layout sessions in Apple WWDC sessions.